# Division algorithm for zeros in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe:

```
 a   b
-5   1
 4  -2
 0   0
 1   0
 0   3
```

And I want to divide:
x = df.a / df.b

Obviously I'll get division by zero errors or inf as a result. But I want to use such an algorithm for division (pseudo code):

```
def CalcRatio(a, b):
    ratio = a / b
    if (isinf(ratio) or isnan(ratio)):
        ratio = (1 + a) / (1 + b)
    return ratio
```

How can I do this with pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take this approach

```
d1 = df.a / df.b
d2 = df.a.add(1) / df.b.add(1)

d1.replace(np.inf, np.nan).fillna(d2)

0   -5.0
1   -2.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    0.0
dtype: float64
```

---

Another approach
`df.b == 0` evaluates to `True` when `b` is zero (obviously).  But when you add this column, it only adds `1` to rows where `b` is zero.  Then you do the division.

```
d1 = df.add(df.b == 0, 0)
d1.a / d1.b
```

Comment: Actually this is much faster than my method: `1000 loops, best of 3: 346 µs per loop` +1 about 4X faster, this is timed just on the replace call though, if we time the whole thing: `1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop` so marginally faster but faster still by 0.30ms

Comment: `1000 loops, best of 3: 691 µs per loop` even faster for last one

Comment: Thanks @EdChum :-)

Comment: Used the last approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.isinf` and `np.isnan` in your code to do what you want using `apply` row-wise:

```
In [207]:

def CalcRatio(a, b):
    ratio = a / b
    if (np.isinf(ratio) or np.isnan(ratio)):
        ratio = (1 + a) / (1 + b)
    return ratio
​
df.apply(lambda x: CalcRatio(x['a'],x['b']), axis=1)

Out[207]:
0   -5.0
1   -2.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    0.0
dtype: float64
```

A vectorised method would be to use `np.where` and pass the conditions in the `True` case to return the alternate result, otherwise to perform division as before:

```
In [208]:
np.where(np.isinf(df['a']/df['b']) | pd.isnull(df['a']/df['b']), (1 + df['a']) / (1 + df['b']), df['a']/df['b'])

Out[208]:
array([-5., -2.,  1.,  2.,  0.])
```

**timings**

For a 5K row df:

```
In [213]:
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: CalcRatio(x['a'],x['b']), axis=1)
%timeit np.where(np.isinf(df['a']/df['b']) | pd.isnull(df['a']/df['b']), (1 + df['a']) / (1 + df['b']), df['a']/df['b'])

1 loops, best of 3: 225 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop
```

We can see here that the vectorised method scales much better than `apply` which is just iterating over each row, here ~170x faster, I expect the numpy method to scale much better for large datasets

**new timings**

```
In [218]:
%%timeit 
d1 = df.a / df.b
d2 = df.a.add(1) / df.b.add(1)    ​
d1.replace(np.inf, np.nan).fillna(d2)

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop

In [219]:
%%timeit
d1 = df.add(df.b == 0, 0)
d1.a / d1.b

1000 loops, best of 3: 691 µs per loop
```

The above are @piRSquared's answers which are noticeably faster

Comment: I don't want NaN or inf for rows 2 and 3.
For row 2: 0 / 0 = NaN. So I want to get (1 + 0) / (1 + 0) = 1
For row 3: 1 / 0 = inf. So I want to get (1 + 1) / (1 + 0) = 2

Comment: What do you want instead?

Comment: Thank for the answer though. Sorry for my first incomplete comment. I accidently posted it.

Comment: Normally it's useful to post the desired output, I took your code and modded to suit your needs, I'll see if I can figure out a vectorised way of doing this

Comment: Thanks for timing measures